# How do I list the versions of the libraries Android SDK Manager has installed?

Tags: android, android-studio

While reading [Setting Up Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) for Android Studio, I read:

> Add a new build rule under dependencies for the latest version of play-services. For example:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
}
```

However, the article didn't say how to determine the latest version of play-services.

Android SDK Manager doesn't provide this information:

[image: Android SDK Manager]

How do you find out what versions of the play services library are installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OS X, the libraries are installed under `~/Library/Android/sdk/extras`. You can list the libraries with their versions using:

```
pushd ~/Library/Android/sdk/extras > /dev/null; find . | egrep '([0-9]+\.){2}[0-9]+$'; popd > /dev/null
```

which will produce a listing like:

```
./google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/7.0.0
./google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/7.3.0
./google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/6.5.87
./google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/7.0.0
./google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/7.3.0
```

Note, you'll have to put colons in the right places to transforms these directory listings into Gradle compile statements. For example, play-services in the listing above becomes:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
```

Comment: More generally, the Android Repository is in `$ANDROID_SDK/extras/android/m2repository`, and the Google Repository is in `$ANDROID_SDK/extras/google/m2repository`, where `$ANDROID_SDK` is wherever you installed the Android SDK.